# Not able to show Font Awesome Icons

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

I'm failing to show Font Awesome icons on my app (only this page)! The icons are showing on the other pages but not on this one I don't know why! and yes I'm importing it in my index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

A link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-ives-uv7ocv?file=/Post.jsx) for better viewing

Here the code:

```
export default function Post({ post }) {
  return (
    <div className="coupon-container">
      <div className="coupon">
        <div className="content">
          <h2>TITLE GOES HERE</h2>
          <h1>
            TEXT <span>TEXT</span>
          </h1>
        </div>

        <div className="couponValidity">
          <i className="fa fa-solid fa-timer"></i>
          <p>SOME TEXT GOES HERE</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have a look at React Icons here [Link](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/). I found using this is easier than importing the whole font awesome icons cdn.

Comment: There is no `.fa-timer` class in fontaweomse v6.1.1, you can check if it's working by changing the `fa-timer` to `fa-user`, it worked fine for me

Answer (score 1):

The icon you're using doesn't exist on the style you've imported. as I see [the timer icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/timer?s=solid&f=classic) is a pro icon. but if you choose another icon, like:

```html
<i className="fa fa-user"></i>
```

then the icon is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

this works on me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
</head>
<body>
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <p>SOME TEXT GOES HERE</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is pure HTML not react.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.